# React CSS animations only work with style attribute

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a component that changes className based on it's state. I noticed that animations only work when I put them in the `style` attribute.

Codesandbox: When we uncomment line 15, animation works properly, even though I have the same css properties in Button.css.

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-babycat-wfpkpi?file=/src/components/Button.js

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the "double quotes" from the CSS rule:

From this:

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  transition: "all .5s ease";
}
```

To this:

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

**Tip:** always check the CSS rules via the Browser Inspector

[image]